# Codeigniter: How to make a desc order between 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

So I am using CodeIgniter and DataMapper. I made something like a wall where you can view **articles** **link posts** **image posts**. This are 3 different tables and each one of them have column called 'pubdate'. At the moment when you view the wall where all of them are displayed and there are **old articles** but newer **link posts**, because they don't 'share' the same pubdate and it is ordering correctly for each table individually.

Any ideas how to make them with kind of shared pubdate so when I upload a new image post to be at the top of my Wall page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your solution is UNION.** Since you are fetching data from 3 different table that has no relations between them, so better to use `UNION`. Also codeigniter's `active record` doesn't support `UNION`, so you have to write the whole sql query. Check this out -

```
$sql = "(SELECT colA, colB, pubdate as dt FROM articles) UNION
        (SELECT colM, colN, pubdate as dt FROM link_posts) UNION 
        (SELECT colX, colZ, pubdate as dt FROM image_posts)
        ORDER BY dt DESC
       ";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: how would this look in DataMapper PHP for CodeIgniter ? At the moment I have 3 loops in my Controller and also I am using Codeigniter's parsing template.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect each table and select rows from these tables.After that, you can merge these array's and sort by the date.I think, it's worst idea about that but it's most likely run successful.

Also, you can connect these tables with one Wall table that has got a **ID** and **InsertionDate** you can create your wall feeds by the those fields.